# I can not align the text inside the data grid horizontally in wpf C#

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to align my columns in the datagrid. How should I do this? I also used HorizontalContentAlignment = "Center" but it did not work. Thank you for your help

```
    <DataGrid Margin="0,69,0,0" x:Name="dgv_Useradmin" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Background="Azure"
              FontFamily="B Roya" FontWeight="Bold" FontStretch="UltraCondensed" BorderBrush="#29bb89" OpacityMask="#e84545" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              CanUserAddRows="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Bisque" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" SelectedIndex="0" LoadingRow="Dgv_Useradmin_OnLoadingRow">

        <!--DataColumn-->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RN" Width="65" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={convertor:RowToIndexConverter}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LogID" Binding="{Binding LogID}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pass" Binding="{Binding PassWord}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding NumberPhone}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Show the markup.
Which element are you setting HorizontalContentAlignment on?
If for DataGrid, then this refers to the rows themselves and does not make sense, since you need alignment in the cells.
You need to set a template and/or style for the cells and specify the desired alignment in them.

Comment: @EldHasp So what should I do ?? I want to align my entire column in the data grid

Comment: Set the column to be of type DataGridTemplateColumn.
In the cell template, set the TextBlock with the alignment you want.

Comment: @EldHasp I provided my code, please tell me where to use textblock
Thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shown for one column.
For the rest of the columns, the same is true.

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RN" Width="65">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={convertor:RowToIndexConverter}}"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <!--If editing is envisaged-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={convertor:RowToIndexConverter}}"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LogID" Binding="{Binding LogID}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pass" Binding="{Binding PassWord}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding NumberPhone}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy just one more question
How do I fold the header in the middle ??

Answer (score 0):

To center the heading, you need to give it a style:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```